# how to bind the same javascript function to an input change and a button click

Tags: javascript, ajax, button, input

I have the following script

```
$(function(){
    $('.input1_class, .input2_class, <many other input classes go here>').bind('change', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "<%= update_fields_projects_url %>",
            data: {
                input1: $('.input1_class').val(),
                input2: $('.input2_class').val(),
                <other inputs go here>
            }
        });
    });
});
```

this is working fine, so if any input is modified, the proper actions are executed and ajax update also runs fine.

Now I wanted to trigger the same ajax request from the click of the following button

```
<input type=button id=update_button_id value="Update Fields" class=update_button_class>
```

I was about to duplicate the previous function by changing the header as follows, which I think would work

```
$(function(){
    $('.update_button_class').bind('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "<%= update_fields_projects_url %>",
            data: {
                input1: $('.input1_class').val(),
                input2: $('.input2_class').val(),
                <other inputs go here>
            }
        });
    });
});
```

but I thought that's not a good solution, because any subsequent changes would have to done in both functions at the same time.

I wonder if there is a better way to write this function only once and to trigger it either from an input "change" or a button "click"

Update1:

I changed to this

```
function updateFields(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_fields_projects_url %>",
        data: {
            input1: $('.input1_class').val(),
            input2: $('.input2_class').val(),
            <other inputs go here>
        }
    });
}

$('.input1_class, .input2_class, <many other input classes go here>').change(updateFields);

<input type=button id=apply_button_id value="Apply Updates" class=apply_button_class onClick="updateFields();">
```

Update2 :

I also tried

```
$('.input1_class, .input2_class, ...').bind('change',updateFields);
```

and that did not work either

Update3 :

The following is what worked for me

```
function updateFields(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "<%= update_fields_projects_url %>",
        data: {
            input1: $('.input1_class').val(),
            input2: $('.input2_class').val(),
            <other inputs go here>
        }
    });
}

$(function(){
    $('.input1_class, .input2_class, ...').bind('change',updateFields);
});

<input type=button id=apply_button_id value="Apply Updates" class=apply_button_class onClick="updateFields();">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the function a name:

```
function func(){

}

$("...").change(func);

<a href="" onclick="func()">Blah</a>
```

Or even:

```
<a id="link">Blah</a>
```

And then:

```
$("...").change(func);

$("#link").click(func);
```

Comment: shouldn't it be `onclick="func();"`? or it also works without the parenthesis?

Comment: @ajax333221 it needs the parentheses

Comment: Oops!  As @JibiAbraham said, it is required.  Answer has been edited.

Comment: definitely avoid using the onclick version of this. But in general the principle is sound.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt responses. I hanged as indicated in Update 1 above. Button click works fine but input change does not trigger any ajax requests anymore.

Comment: If that's your actual HTML in the edit, not sure if it's the problem or not, but try quoting the attribute values.  type=button for example should be type="button"

Comment: Thanks Corbin. Actually, the button part works fine. The problem I have is that the input change does not trigger ajax requests anymore, it used to do so.

Comment: @rh4games ah sorry, misread your comment.  Have you tried checking the Chrome Developer Tools console for any errors that may be happening (or Firebug in FF or Dev Tools in IE)?

Comment: I'm using Safari. The web inspector console does not show anything and the server logs do not show any requests coming in ;-(

Comment: @rh4games just to make sure, you didn't put the () in the change(), right?  You have it like change(func) and not change(func())?

Comment: Thanks @Corbin for the follow up. Yes, I had it just like this $('.input1_class, .input2_class, ...').change(updateFields) ; I also tried $('.input1_class, .input2_class, ...').bind('change',updateFields) and that did not work either.